# Using boost::asio to find all reachable ips on a subnet

Tags: c++, windows, networking, boost-asio

I would like a way to use boost to find all reachable ips(responding to a ping) on a subnet.

i.e. given subnet = 10.10.10.0 and ips 10.10.10.1-5 that are reachable, the result should be a list: 10.10.10.1 , ... , 10.10.10.5

Currently I have a script that pings the subnet and checks the arp cache for reachable ips.

Comment: What do you mean by "reachable"?  Responds to pings?  Has a certain TCP port open and is accepting connections?  Just has a certain TCP open?  Toggles a light in the Vatican when you subject it to a specific sequence of UDP packets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have a [ping example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/icmp/ping.cpp) in the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html).